# Passing function by variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've this situation:

```
<script>
var cb;
function doSomething(c) {
    cb = c();
}

cb();
</script>
```

But it doesn't work. I want to set a variable as function, to make a callback called by other functions.. Some ideas?

Comment: c.call is what you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c()` executes the function and returns a value, you need to pass a reference to it:

```
cb = c
```

Also, you should call the function `doSomething(func)` to make the assignment.

```
doSomething(function(){ alert('hello'); });
cb(); // "Hello"
```

But if what you want is a *callback* then you don't need a global variable:

```
function doSomething(callback) {
  // do something
  if (callback) callback();
}
```

When you run the function with another function as parameter the callback will run.

Comment: Also, you should call the function doSomething

Comment: Thank you! However: "But if what you want is a callback then you don't need a global variable", yes, I need 'cause a I need to recall that function from other functions and I can't pass it as arg

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign cb first with your function:

```
<script>
var cb;
function doSomething(c) {
    cb = c;
}

var myFunc = function(){
   window.alert("test");
}

doSomething(myFunc);

cb();
</script>
```

And if you do `cb=c();` you will execute function `c` instantly and return the value to `cb` if you want the variable `cb` as the result of `c`, do like this. otherwise, assign without running it.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options to set a variable to a functiion

1. `var fn = functionname;`
2. `var fn = function(param){};` this will be an anonymous function
3. `var fn = function FunctionName(param){};` this will be a named function, comes in handy when debugging, since it will present you with a function name (`console.log(c);`

You cann call it like `var returnVal = fn();` or pass it to a function `var returnVal = myFunc(fn);` where myFunc calls the param, let it be `inFn` it like `inFn();`

What might be interesting to note:
Since such a function is related to the global context, you can bind an object to it alter its scope. That gives you the possibility of `this`referencing the bound object. (Be aware, bind is not supported by all browsers as it is defined [ECMAScript 5](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.5), but there are quite some polyfills out there.)

- `fn.bind(object);`

Or call it in another context with `fn.call(object, param1, param2)` or `fn.apply(object, [param1, param2])`. Nice write up on this [Link to odetocode.com/blog](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx).